# Fetching only Recent(recent) mail by IMAP in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to fetch new incoming mail through IMAP protocol ..my sample code is --

```
task :receive_mail_new => :environment do 
#require 'rubygems'
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true,nil, false)
#imap.authenticate('LOGIN','debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com','****')
imap.login('test@example.com', '********')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |id|
envelope = imap.fetch(id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
end
imap.logout()
imap.disconnect()
end
```

the problem is that

```
 imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |id|
```

this line is not executed ...how can i fetch only recent mail? can any help me

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, `RECENT` does not mean what you think it does, try `UNSEEN` instead. `RECENT` means "noone has had the opportunity to see even the subject of this message before you".